# Issue with useReducer hook and reducer function

Tags: reactjs

I think it's mainly an issue with my reducer function but basically I'm trying to add and delete components. Adding works fine. Deleting doesn't work correctly.  I put a console log in the onClick when I create a new component and it shows unique ids but it seems like it's not getting passed correctly into the reducer or something. If anyone has any ideas, I'm all ears.

Reducer function

```
export default function reducer(state: any, action: any) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_COMPONENT":
      return {
        ...state,
        components: [...state.components, action.payload],
      };
    case "DELETE_COMPONENT":
      return {
        ...state,
        components: state.components.filter(
          (component: any) => component.id == action.payload
        ),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Here for the Delete, it's filtering and checking for an id, with it this way (component.id == action.payload), it deletes all of the components.  If I have !=== action.payload, it doesn't delete anything.

Context

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import ComponentReducer from "./ComponentReducer";

const NewComponentState: NewComponentsState = {
  components: [],
  addComponent: () => {},
  deleteComponent: () => {},
};

export const NewComponentContext =
  React.createContext<NewComponentsState>(NewComponentState);

export const NewComponentProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
 
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ComponentReducer, NewComponentState);

  const addComponent = (component: any) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_COMPONENT",
      payload: component
    });
  };
  const deleteComponent = (id: any) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "DELETE_COMPONENT",
      payload: id,
    });
  };
  return (
    <NewComponentContext.Provider
      value={{ components: state.components, deleteComponent, addComponent }}
    >
      {children}
    </NewComponentContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Notes component. This is the component I've been testing this with

```
import { Menu,Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import React, { useState, Fragment, useContext } from "react";
import NoteColorChanger from "./NoteColor";
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';
import { NewComponentContext } from "../../../Context/NewComponentContext";

interface INote {
  id: any
}
const Note: React.FC <INote> = ({ id }) => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState<string>()
  const [title, setTitle] = useState<string>()
  const [color, setColor] = useState<any>()
  const [position, setPosition] = useState<any>({x: 0, y: 0})

  const {deleteComponent} = useContext(NewComponentContext)

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setContent(event.target.value)
  };

  const handleColor = (notecolor: any) => {
    setColor(notecolor)
  }

  const trackPosition = (pos:any) => {
    setPosition({x: pos.x, y: pos.y})
  }

  return ( 
    <div className={`${color} h-64 w-64 bg-yellow-200 text-black rounded-lg p-2 shadow-lg`}>
      <div className="flex justify-between items-center pb-6">
        <h1 className="font-bold font-Inter">Note</h1>
        <Menu>
          <Menu.Button>
            <div className={`hover:${color} p-1 rounded-lg ease-in-out duration-100`}>
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                className="h-6 w-6"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                stroke="currentColor"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth={1}
                  d="M5 12h.01M12 12h.01M19 12h.01M6 12a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zm7 0a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zm7 0a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0z"
                />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </Menu.Button>
          <Transition
            as={Fragment}
            enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
            enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
            enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
            leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
            leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
            leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
          >
            <Menu.Items
              as="div"
              className={`bg-gray-100 font-Inter w-64 shadow-lg rounded-lg absolute translate-y-24 -translate-x-2 z-50`}
            >
              <Menu.Item>
                {({ active }) => (
                  <div
                    id="color"
                    className={` flex items-center py-2 px-3 rounded-lg w-full`}
                  >
                    {<NoteColorChanger handleColor={handleColor}/>}
                    
                    
                  </div>
                )}
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item>
                {({ active }) => (
                  <button
                    id="Todo"
                    className={`${
                      active ? "bg-blue-500 text-white" : "text-black"
                    } flex items-center py-2 px-3 rounded-lg w-full`}
                  >
                    <svg
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      className="h-6 w-6 mr-3"
                      fill="none"
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                    >
                      <path
                        strokeLinecap="round"
                        strokeLinejoin="round"
                        strokeWidth={2}
                        d="M11 5H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v11a2 2 0 002 2h11a2 2 0 002-2v-5m-1.414-9.414a2 2 0 112.828 2.828L11.828 15H9v-2.828l8.586-8.586z"
                      />
                    </svg>
                    Edit Title
                  </button>
                )}
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item>
                {({ active }) => (
                  <li
                    onClick={() => deleteComponent(id)}
                    className={`${
                      active ? "bg-blue-500 text-white" : " text-black"
                    } flex items-center py-2 px-3 cursor-pointer rounded-lg`}
                  >
                    <svg
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      className="h-6 w-6 mr-3"
                      fill="none"
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                    >
                      <path
                        strokeLinecap="round"
                        strokeLinejoin="round"
                        strokeWidth={2}
                        d="M19 7l-.867 12.142A2 2 0 0116.138 21H7.862a2 2 0 01-1.995-1.858L5 7m5 4v6m4-6v6m1-10V4a1 1 0 00-1-1h-4a1 1 0 00-1 1v3M4 7h16"
                      />
                    </svg>
                    Delete Note
                  </li>
                )}
              </Menu.Item>
              
            </Menu.Items>
          </Transition>
        </Menu>
      </div>

      <textarea
        className={`${color} bg-yellow-200 font-Inter w-full h-48 border-none focus:border-none focus:ring-0 resize-none`}
        onChange={() => {handleChange}}
      />
    </div>
   
  );
};
export default Note;
```

menu component

```
import React, { useContext, Fragment, useState } from "react"
import { NewComponentContext } from "../../Context/NewComponentContext"
import { Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import Note from "./Note/Note";
import TodoList from "./Todo/TodoList";
import Photo from "./Photo/Photo";

const NewComponentMenu = () => {
    const { addComponent } = useContext(NewComponentContext)
    const [id, setId] = useState<number>(0)

    const newComponent = (component: any) => {
        setId(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000))
        addComponent(component)
    }
    return (
      <div className="w-6 h-6 mt-4 ml-4 shadow-md text-gray-800 font-Inter z-50">
        <Menu>
          <Menu.Button>
            <div className="p-1 rounded-lg bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 ease-in-out duration-100">
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                className="h-6 w-6 text-blue-50"
                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                fill="currentColor"
              >
                <path
                  fillRule="evenodd"
                  d="M10 3a1 1 0 011 1v5h5a1 1 0 110 2h-5v5a1 1 0 11-2 0v-5H4a1 1 0 110-2h5V4a1 1 0 011-1z"
                  clipRule="evenodd"
                />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </Menu.Button>
          <Transition
            as={Fragment}
            enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
            enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
            enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
            leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
            leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
            leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
          >
            <Menu.Items as="div" className="w-60 shadow-lg rounded-lg bg-white">
              <h1 className="text-center font-Inter text-2xl pb-2">Items</h1>
 
              <Menu.Item>
                {({ active }) => (
                  <li
                    onClick={() => newComponent(<Note id={id}/>) }
                    className={`${
                      active ? "bg-blue-500 text-white" : " text-black"
                    } flex items-center py-2 px-3 cursor-pointer rounded-lg`}
                  >
                    <svg
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      className="h-6 w-6 mr-3"
                      fill="none"
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                    >
                      <path
                        strokeLinecap="round"
                        strokeLinejoin="round"
                        strokeWidth={2}
                        d="M11 5H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v11a2 2 0 002 2h11a2 2 0 002-2v-5m-1.414-9.414a2 2 0 112.828 2.828L11.828 15H9v-2.828l8.586-8.586z"
                      />
                    </svg>
                    Note
                  </li>
                )}
              </Menu.Item>
            </Menu.Items>
          </Transition>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default NewComponentMenu;
```

Comment: Hard to tell, but maybe `id` is a number in your component, and a string when passed to your reducer?

It's not type enforced here `const deleteComponent = (id: any) => {` and `"1" !== 1` is true.

Comment: If that's not the cause, then I would add a console log like this: `components: state.components.filter(
          (component: any) => {
console.log(component.id, action.payload)
console.log(component.id !== action.payload)
component.id == action.payload
}
        ),` and that should make it more clear what data the reducer is receiving and whether the boolean is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The issue you have is that you are not passing objects that have an `id` property to the `addComponent` callback. You are passing a JSX literal. Storing JSX into any React state is generally an anti-pattern, you should be storing the data and mapping it to JSX when rendering.

## Solution

Pass an object with `id` property on it. You just need a function to generate an `id` when updating the state, so the `id` state in `NewComponentMenu` is unnecessary.

```
const NewComponentMenu = () => {
  const { addComponent } = useContext(NewComponentContext);

  const newComponent = () => {
    addComponent({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000),
    });
  };

  return (
    ...
    <Menu.Item>
      {({ active }) => (
        <li
          onClick={newComponent}
          className={`${
            active ? "bg-blue-500 text-white" : " text-black"
          } flex items-center py-2 px-3 cursor-pointer rounded-lg`}
        >
          ...
        </li>
      )}
    </Menu.Item>
    ...
  );
};
```

Now that you are storing data element objects with an `id` property, the delete case should work.

When rendering the `state.components` you will need to map to the `Note` components.

```
const { components } = useContext(NewComponentContext);

...

{components.map(el => <Note id={el.id}/>)}
```

Comment: Interesting. JSX literals and an anti pattern. Thank you this works great and I learned something new. Well I guess a follow up question now would be how would I distinguish between different components? Doing it this way doesn't allow me to add other things from the menu like a Todo list for example. If I add it in the map function then it just renders both which makes sense.

Comment: There may be a better way but I just gave each component a type id and used conditionals inside the map and it works.

Comment: @ckam03 That is pretty close to the pattern suggested by React: [Choosing the type at runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime).